# gpg crypt and decrypt

Tags: linux, console, console-application, gnupg

I am trying to crypt and decrypt Strings.
Now I have done this:

```
mis@fasan:~$ echo "hallo" | gpg --symmetric --pgp8 --cipher-algo AES256 > /tmp/1
Enter passphrase:
Repeat passphrase:
mis@fasan:~$
mis@fasan:~$ cat /tmp/1 | gpg --decrypt
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
Enter passphrase: 
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
hallo
mis@fasan:~$
```

It works just like I want it to work. Now I have tried it with a passphrase out of a file, but it didn't work:

```
mis@fasan:~$ echo "hallo" | gpg --symmetric --pgp8 --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase-fd 0 < /home/mis/testgpg > /tmp/1
Reading passphrase from file descriptor 0    
mis@fasan:~$
mis@fasan:~$ cat /tmp/1 | gpg --decrypt
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
```

It is very interesting, that he asks for the passphrase. If I write a wrong one, I get an error message, but if I write the right passphrase, I do not get my cryptet String. 
My target is to reach this:

```
mis@fasan:~$ echo "hallo" | gpg --symmetric --pgp8 --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase-fd 0 < /home/mis/testgpg > /tmp/1
Reading passphrase from file descriptor 0    
mis@fasan:~$
mis@fasan:~$ cat /tmp/1 | gpg --decrypt --passphrase-fd 0 < /home/mis/testgpg
Reading passphrase from file descriptor 0    
gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof
mis@fasan:~$
```

But this doesn't work either. Does anyone know, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to push both the test to encrypt (`echo "hallo" |`) and the pass phrase (`< /home/mis/testgpg`) through the same file descriptor (0, which is stdin). Only one of those redirection can succeed and it is the pass phrase. Use a different file or file descriptor for the two tasks.

E.g., using file descriptor #3 for the pass phrase:

```
echo "hallo" | gpg --symmetric --pgp8 --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase-fd 3 3< /home/mis/testgpg > /tmp/1
```